# Expectation of absolute sum of squared normal distributions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Let $u_i$ be a standard normal distribution for all $i$. All $u_i$'s are independent of each other. I want to compute the expectation of:

$$| \sum_i u_i^2 \lambda_i |$$

Where $\lambda_i$ is real but can be negative. I found that the $u_i^2$ are Gamma distributions, and a sum of Gamma distributions is again a Gamma distribution (but I'm unsure since they are scaled). But how to deal with the absolute value?

If this is untractable I'm wondering if we can compute this expectation if each $u_i$ has a symmetric uniform distribution. The expectation of $u_i^2 \lambda_i$ is straightforward to compute, but the sum and absolute value again seem tricky.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your question is, "How do I apply the absolute value to the sum of gamma distributions?"

In this case, the absolute value is used to find the integer associated with the complex plane of the sum. When a number with an imaginary part (a complex number) is returned by the sum, the absolute value solves for this by returning the distance of the complex number from the origin of a real-imaginary graph. For example:

If $|3+4i|$ was returned by the sum of the gamma distributions, then the result would be $3^2+4^2=5^2$, so $5$ would be returned by $|3+4i|$.

However, this would only apply in the case that $λ_{i}$ is negative, as that is the scenario that the gamma distribution "jumps onto the imaginary plane" as I like to call it. Otherwise, the sum should return a real number, and the absolute value is easy to calculate.